# Deriving an algorithm to compute a stabbing line existsence for a set of line segments on a plane

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given a collection $S$ of $N$ segments in the plane, devise an algorithm that decides if
there is a line, intersecting all members of $S$ (stabbing line) and, if so, construct it.

Originally this task from *Preparata, Shamos "Computational Geometry. An Introducion"*, exercise 7.2.
I don't know where can I begin. There is similar question on math.stackexchange.com, but it doesnot contain an answer.

Maybe you could give some ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into the fact that you can always construct a line between exactly two segments (as long as they aren't perpendicular to each other)? If you draw a line between two of them, then your line possibilities are severely restricted because it has to _stay_ within those two segments. Does that help any?

Comment: @thePretzelMan, but we can construct line between two segments, even if they perpendicular to each other

Comment: @thePretzelMan, yes, it helped since we need to draw region, in which we can intersect other potential segments. But how can I summarize it to arbitrary-number segments?

Answer (score 1):

Do you now the domain called [Integral Geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3930863) that has other names such as Stochastic Geometry, Geometric measure theory  ?

In this framework, a straight line, written under its so-called "polar form":

$$x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta = p,$$

is associated with point $(\theta,p)$ in a "cylindrical space" $H$.

Certain sets of lines will be represented as subsets of $H$ with rather remarkable shapes. Dualy, sine curves in $H$ will be associated to points in the ordinary geometrical space.

For example, being given a point $M$ in the ordinary plane with polar coordinates $(\rho_M, \theta_M)$, the set of lines passing through $A$ is represented in $H$ by the sine curve with equation:

$$\rho=\rho_M \cos(\theta-\theta_M)$$

As a consequence, lines that separate 2 points $A$ and $B$, with resp. polar coordinates $(\rho_A, \theta_A)$ and $(\rho_B, \theta_B)$ (which is equivalent to say that such lines intersect segment $[AB]$) are "positionned" in $H$ in the area between the 2 sine curves with equations:

$$\rho=\rho_A \cos(\theta-\theta_A) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \rho=\rho_B \cos(\theta-\theta_B) \tag{1}$$

Therefore, your problem can be implemented in this space by showing that the set of "points" in $H$ (each point representing a line), defined by a set of $n$ constraints of type (1), is non void.

Some references: an answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3930640). See also [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2816931) for the result called "Cauchy-Crofton theorem" allowing to attribute a "degree of margin" one can have in such issues using measure theory.

Remark: The transformation I just described is used under the name "Hough Transform" in image processing.

---

Edit: Here is an apparently different representation using [pole polar duality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3842796) "twining" in a natural way a line to a point, therefore a set of lines to a set of points. In fact this representation is equivalent to the one I have explained before. The big advantage of this representation is that it doesn't need an auxiliary representation space: we always work in the initial space. Technically, it's very simple : to a line with equation $ax+by=1$ is associated its pole $(a,b)$.

Using this correspondence, we can associate to any line segment $[AB]$ the set of lines that intersect it, or more exactly their poles, and the result is simple; the set of lines intersection line segment $[AB]$ is the region situated between the to polar lines of $A$ and $B$ resp. Here is the case (line segment with magenta color). Thousands of random lines intersecting $[AB]$ have been considered and their poles represented by red points materializing the area between the two polar lines of extreme points $A$ and $B$:

[image]

Doing this for line segments $[A_kB_k], \ \ k=1,2...N$ gives a constructive testing method for finding a stabbing line (or proving that none exists) by using **simplex method** (I must check this idea) which could be a very efficient method.

Comment: Seems interesting! And no, I'm not even familiar with Stochastic Geometry

Comment: See the references I just gave to get a little idea about the subject. Tomorrow, I will surely find more specific references.

Comment: I have improved this Edit with a figure and the idea to use the simplex method.

Comment: See [this](https://web.mat.upc.edu/carlos.seara/data/publications/articles/geometry_lp.pdf)